# File reading, writing and appending in TCL

Tags: file-io, tcl

In TCL, how to append different content into a single file using the `for` loop or `foreach` loop?

Comment: What do you mean by "different content"?

Answer (score 24):

Did you mean something like that?

```
set fo [open file a]
foreach different_content {"text 1" "text two" "something else" "some content"} {
  puts $fo $different_content
}
close $fo
```

You open file `file` in mode `a` (append) and write to the file descriptor (`$fo` in the example).

*Update:* If you want to append variable contents, you have to change the script to:

```
set fo [open file a]
foreach different_content [list $data1 $data2 $data3 $data4] {
  puts $fo $different_content
}
close $fo
```

Comment: its ok fine. But i have one more problem. The problem is that suppose if i declare like that:  set data1 "connect / as sysdba;\n"
set data2  {spool $TMP/"DBTEST"_dbmode.txt}
set data3  "\nSELECT OPEN_MODE, NAME, CONTROLFILE_TYPE FROM V\$DATABASE;\n" and so on.... If i want to write in a file so how can i substitute the data1,data2 ..... values. Exactly what i want i want to put the $data1 value in foreach loop, so how should i do, Please help me..
set data4 "spool off;\n"

Comment: @galvin: I'm not fully sure if I understood you correctly, but I updated my answer.

Comment: see the situation I define the variable value Let it be : set data1 "This is Data1 value" and second is set data2 "This is Data2 Value" Now i want to write the value of variable data1 and data2 using the foreach loop, so How can i should do, Please help me.   Here i am doing like this : set fo [open $filename w]

foreach different_content {data1 data2} {

  puts $fo $different_content
}
close $fo
}  But it is not working .???????????????

Comment: @galvin: If you do it like this you will write "data1" and "data2" to the file. You have to do e.g. `foreach different_content "$data1 $data2" {puts $fo $different_content}`

Answer (score 1):

The following code creates a text file in folder `'P'` and writes into it.

```
set fid [open p:\\temp.txt w]

puts $fid "here   is the first line."

close $fid
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is fine for reading from a file, where `sample.tcl` file is available in 'p' folder.

**Heading**

```
set fp [open "p://sample.tcl" r]

set file_data [read $fp]

puts $file_data

close $fp
```